# Can multiple custom post types share a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I'm considering rebuilding a drupal site in wordpress and am still wrapping my head around the differences between the systems - particularly cck/fields and custom content types and the different ways to use taxonomy.

I would like to know if two custom content types can share one custom taxonomy.  In drupal I can limit the posting of a particular content type to a group of users and then that posting can have taxonomy that is only shared with one or more other content types (but not all types).

Leaving the user aspect out which appears possible with role scoper, can you do this with wordpress?  I've only seen custom content type with custom taxonomy but no way to share a given taxonomy between 2 or more custom content types without recreating it in two places or enabling it globally through categories/tags...

Thanks,
-Chad.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251877/get-post-according-to-current-taxonomy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Sharing a taxonomy between CPTs

> I would like to know if two custom content types can share one custom taxonomy.

Simple said: **Yes, they can**.

### How to share

You should **always register** custom taxonomies and post types **to each other** as early as possible.

Wrap your registration process in a function, hooked to the `init` hook at the default priority.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: Register $CPT and $CT */
add_action('init', function() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'some_custom_tax',
        'some_post_type',
        $array_of_arguments
    );
    register_post_type(
        'some_post_type',
        [
            'taxonomies' => [ 'some_custom_tax' ],
            // other arguments
        ]
    );
}, 10 ); # <-- default priority
```

It doesn't matter if you use the 2<sub>nd</sub> argument for `register_taxonomy()` or if you use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`, as both do the same: They take the `$GLOBALS['wp_taxonomies']` array and assign it the post type object (type).

### Important note

Just make sure that you register the CT and the CPT to each other at when registering them. Else you won't have access to that interconnection during query hooks.

Comment: One issue I've found is that the admin doesn't correctly display the number of posts for a CPT once the shared CT is used elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. The question asks about registering a CT to multiple CPTs. This answer looks like it depicts registering a CPT and a CT to each other both ways.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy Yes, the answer does. For multiple reasons. Please read the answer in detail.

Answer (score 14):

I was able to achieve this easily by passing array of all the Custom post types I want to share the taxonomy, So my code looked like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );
 function build_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy( 'some_custom_tax', array('some_post_type_1','some_post_type_2'), array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Custom Tax Title', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );   
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO. Concise and to the point.

Answer (score 6):

[From the Codex:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

> ### taxonomies
>
> (array) (optional) An array of registered taxonomies like category or post_tag that will be used with this post type. This can be used in lieu of calling  `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` directly. Custom taxonomies still need to be registered with [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

When you register your post type you assign the taxonomies it supports, or use [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) at some other point to add the taxonomy to the post type.

You can assign a taxonomy to as many post types as you like. Taxonomies are not tied to a particular post type.