# I have a custom taxonomy assigned to two post types. How do I create URLs for different term archives for each post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I am working on a site for a client and am using a plugin that adds an "**event**" custom post type and an "**event-category**" taxonomy.

I have also attached the "event-category" taxonomy to the default Wordpress "post" post type using the **register_taxonomy_for_object_type** function.

Now I have the following working URL scheme:

- Post are accessed using the URL structure
  **site-name.com/article/post-slug**
- Events are accesed using the URL
  structure **site-name.com/event/event-slug**
- Event category term archives
  have the URL structure **site-name.com/events/event-category-slug**

I made the event category term archives display only events by using a **pre_get_posts** action with the following code:

```
if (!$query->is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_tax('event-category')) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'event');
}
```

My problem is that I want to also have category archive pages that show only posts.

If possible these would ideally be accessed with the URL **site-name.com/articles/event-category-slug**

But if that's not possible it would be OK to have a different URL, as long as it leads to a page listing just posts in that particular event category.

Any help with the rewrite rules needed to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
I've found some articles that describe similar problems but I haven't been able to make them work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to find a solution:

First of all, the **pre_get_posts** action that I originally had wasn't good, because both the events and the posts are displayed using the same template (*taxonomy-event-category.php*). The code that I wrote in pre_get_posts forced wordpress to display only events in that template, so I removed it.

I replaced it with this code, which filters the query according to the post_type query var:

```
if (is_tax('event-category')) {
    $query->set('post_type', get_query_var('post_type', 'event'));
}
```

(In case there is not post_type query var, it defaults to events).

Then I added the following rewrite rule, which makes Wordpress recognize the **articles/event-category-slug** URLs

```
add_rewrite_rule('^articles/(?!page)(.+?)(?:/page/([0-9]*))*/?$', 'index.php?post_type=post&event-category=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

The *(?!page)* part of the regex is needed so that the rule doesn't trigger on paged URLs like *articles/page/2*, but still triggers on *articles/event-category-slug/page/2*

I'm not an expert in regex so maybe there's a better way to write that rule, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with the rewrite portion when you registered the custom taxonomy with posts.

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'some-slug', 'with_front' => false)
```

You can replace some-slug with anything you would like. It might be possible to replace it with `article/event-category` to get the results you want.

Setting `with_front` to `false` removes blog as a prefix. If you have changed the blog prefix to article. Then you should be able to set `with_front` to `true` and replace `some-slug` with `event-category

Here is a link with more info on registering custom taxonomies
https://clarknikdelpowell.com/blog/the-right-way-to-do-wordpress-custom-taxonomy-rewrites/

**EDIT:**
Can you do the following completely untested, created example code from link below:

```
register_post_type(
    'post',
    array(
        'taxonomies' => array( 'event-category' )
    ),
    array(
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'some-slug', 'with_front' => false)
        // other arguments may be needed from other registration of taxonomy
    )
);
```

Reference:
[Can multiple custom post types share a custom taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92430/can-multiple-custom-post-types-share-a-custom-taxonomy)

Comment: if you think that the question is a dup, please flag it as one ;)

Comment: The title of the link is the summary, what would you like the answer to be moved to this page. Seems like this page should be marked as duplicate over saying my answer isnt good.

Comment: I changed my comments, didn't see where you were linking to at first ;) Usually outbound links are bad answers if not at least summerized

Comment: How do I do that, I dont see mark as duplicate as a flag for me. Maybe my rep isnt high enough?

Comment: I took a look at that question, but it's not the same problem. In that question the issue is with having two taxonomies tied to one post type. In my case it's two post types sharing a taxonomy. Maybe I could adapt that answer but truthfully I don't know how.

Comment: oh i see, just me reading too fast. Ill work on an edit for my answer

Comment: Regarding your new answer: those parameters are for registering the taxonomy (for the function register_taxonomy), but i'm not the one registering it. The plugin is. I only attach it to the "post" post type using register_taxonomy_for_object_type, which doesn't take those arguments: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type

Comment: @stoi2m1 I don't remeber what is possible with your rep, but I think you should have an option if you click the "flag" link

Comment: @MarkKaplun I have added another update, please have a look and let me know

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way. You probably have to add a rewrite rule to parse a url into the proper wp_query values

Comment: @MarkKaplun heres a page where someone had a similar issue and used rewrites, no answer marked as accpeted so not sure if it actually worked to resolve the issue. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113470/multiple-custom-post-types-using-the-same-taxonomy-url-frustrations

Comment: @MarkKaplun :  I managed to find a solution in the end. The answer is here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226889/i-have-a-custom-taxonomy-assigned-to-two-post-types-how-do-i-create-urls-for-di/229363#229363

Thanks for your help.