# Get post according to current taxonomy

Tags: query, taxonomy

Thanks for any help.

I am in a custom post (not an archive) with a taxonomy.
And I'd like to display :

- some other custom posts
- with this **current taxonomy**

Doesn't seems so hard but for me it does... 
I didn't find the right way to use the term of my tax in the query...

Here is (one of) my try :

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'identite'); // to get my taxonomy

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
echo "$term->slug"; // just for test - ok

   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'example',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'identite',
            'field'    => 'ID',
            'terms'    => $terms
             )
        ),
     );// end args

$query = new WP_Query( $args);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
         $query->the_post();

       // Little pray, but doesn't work

    }//end of while

}
```

I obtain this error message : 
*Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to int in*

Any idea to convert my object and make it readable ?
Thanks a lot

*(edit : I try with the function wp_list_pluck but without success)*

Comment: Did you want to display the posts for each term? Or just a list of non separated posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for `WP_Query`

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'example',
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'identite',
        'field'    => 'ID',
        'terms'    => $term->term_id
         )
    ),
 );// end args
```

OR

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'example',
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'identite',
        'field'    => 'ID',
        'terms'    => array($term->term_id)
         )
    ),
 );// end args
```

`$term` is an object and `tax_query` expects an array of id's.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

You get this error message because of the way you are setting up the `$args` array. In the `tax_query`, you'll want to pass an array of all the terms ids for the current post. Also, the `field` value was incorrect (as seen in the Codex here: [WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)).

The final code should look something like:

```
<?php 

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'identite'); 
$terms_ids = [];

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $terms_ids[] = $term->term_id;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'example',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'identite',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $terms_ids
        )
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        // All the magic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc-Antoine !
I just replaced in the query :
'terms'    => $terms_ids
by 
'terms'    => array($term->term_id)
And the conversion works. Un grand merci !

Comment: My pleasure! Although be aware that this snippet will now only load posts contained in the last category (if you kept the `foreach` part on top). As `wp_get_post_terms` might return an array of categories, the value of `$term` after the foreach will be left at the its last value in the foreach. 

The main point of my sample code was to have posts loaded for every categories that would be selected for the current post.